Palm tree misting system to kill beetle pest "rhino beetle"
In Hawaii we are having a huge issue with this pest called a "rhino beetle" These beetles eat the heart of palms, eventually killing the palm completely. Soon Hawaii will have little or no more coconuts in due to this destructive invasive pest. See the beetle damage here
I have done some tests on live beetles and have found that they die if Eucalyptus concentrate comes into contact with them.
I have built a fogging/mister that is pressurized from water piping and hosing that goes up the palm into the crown where the beetles are attacking. Beetles are nocturnal and actively eat the palm crowns at night, thus my mister runs all night long misting the crown. The nozzles I have in the palm are letting out 2 gph (gallon per hour). The injector manufacturer confirmed the 16 oz pint will become empty once 30 gallons of water pass through it. The math is 30 gallons/2gph = 15 gallons that's 15 hours of run time that will empty the tank..
ex: 7 pm - 1hr run time w a gap between on and off stages of 30 mins of misting all night till 5am. Injecting 4oz of Eucalyptus concentrate into the injector to 12 oz of water in the pint-size injector.
Any ideas for creating / engineering my own home made injector to inject more than just 16 oz of fluids through the hosing system.
I'm also interested to know if anyone has a recommendation on a camera that can be installed in the palm so i can get a visual of the bugs during feeding hours.

So a large tank where you mix the required concentration then deliver it...

Needs to small enough so i can be multiple palms

I know you mean well, but for gods sake stop what you are doing. The pest isn't exactly new. I'm sure there are companies like Monsanto and Dupont that are 20 years into their development process to find a reasonable solution. If this is your passion that's great. Go get a horticulture and management degree and a master's in biochemistry. Also get your pesticide applicator's license with ornamental and tropicals specialization. Go work for a licensed applicator for a couple years while studying up on experiment design and pesticide regulation administration.

Then give Monsanto and Dupont a call, or get a job with the county's research extension center. And a degree in etymology wouldn't hurt, but that can be learned on the job as well.

So you want to be a palm? Not sure that is on topic here...

Plenty of cameras out there where a micro sd is installed and you just supply power. Bug trap bag instead of spray... If you must spray without a big premixed tank, just get the appropriate pumps and valves to mix chemicals into your flow of water.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
